# Were there other wandmakers in Diagon Alley?

Tags: harry-potter

Ginny Weasley was told that, once Olivander was no longer operating his shop, people would get their wands from other makers:

> “Talking of Diagon Alley,’ said Mr Weasley, ‘looks like Ollivander’s gone too.’
>
> ‘The wand-maker?’ said Ginny, looking startled.
>
> ‘That’s the one. Shop’s empty. No sign of a struggle. No one knows whether he left voluntarily or was kidnapped.’
>
> ‘But wands – what’ll people do for wands?’
>
> ‘They’ll make do with other makers,’ said Lupin. ‘But Ollivander was the best, and if the other side have got him it’s not so good for us.”
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 6 (Draco's Detour)*</sup></sub>

Were there other wandmakers in Diagon Alley? Or would you have to go to another village or even another country (or by post) to get a new wand?

[yes, there is a 'second' shop in the Wizarding World park by Universal. I wouldn't consider that canon outside of a secondary source like JKR or something actually referencing that. The second shop in the park is merely one of traffic flow and economics imo - a chance to buy a wand without waiting around for the 'wand ceremony' experience]

Comment: I do find it peculiar that we know of more wand-makers in the US than we do in the UK or Europe.

Comment: In case you want to avoid the dupe, you could probably repose your question as " **Were there other Wandmakers in Diagon Alley during ...... time** "

Comment: nah - don't care about it being a dupe - thanks though @Shreedhar :)

Answer (score 3):

There is possibly one other in Diagon Alley based on film canon:

[Jimmy Kiddell](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Jimmy_Kiddell) owns the shop "Jimmy Kiddell's Wonderful Wands".

This based on a single sighting of a sign hanging in the first film.